# Can I see what other players have named their character in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

On Xbox 360 (not sure about other platforms), I only see other players' Xbox Live account names in the lobby and in-game. **Is there a way to see what my teammates named their characters? Are they able to see the name of my eponymously named male vanguard, Manguard?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only point of the name is that it shows up in singleplayer war assets when you promote from multiplayer. There is no other place it is displayed, except to yourself.

In a way, this kind of makes sense - otherwise, every single guy you promoted from multiplayer would have the same name. This way, at least, you can give your quarians vas Rannonch or other appropriate names.

Answer (score 3):

My friends and I were just checking this earlier actually. Unfortunately, **no**, there does not seem to be any way to publicly display your multiplayer character's name. We thought that clicking on the player name would allow it, but it only gives the stats of the other person's character (class, loadout, etc.), not the name.

For the record, I'm playing the PC version.